# ERROR TypeError: this.X is not a function when trying to call it with Ajax

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm trying to call successLogin() function as below from an Ajax code segment using Typescript in an Ionic v3 project. But it gives this.successLogin() is not a function error. Can anyone suggest a workaround?

```
signin() 
  {
    var ajaxResp = $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "XXX",
      data: { 
        'uid': "50", 
        'pass': "100" 
    }
      })
    .done(function(response){
      let js = JSON.parse(response).data;      
      console.log(js);
      this.successLogin(js);
    });
  }

successLogin(msg){
  console.log(msg);
}
```

I attached an image of the error as well.

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yiCk3.png)

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The issue may be with `this`.

Try binding `this`, or changing the method declaration to:

```
signin = () => 
  { ... }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something like but make sure you are passing json data to ajax request

```
signin() 
  {
    var ajaxResp = $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "XXX",
      dataType: 'json',
      data: { 
        'uid': "50", 
        'pass': "100" 
    },
    success: function(response){     
      successLogin(response);
    },
      });
  }

successLogin(msg){
  console.log(msg);
}
```